# Proof verification of probabilities question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

**Question**:We have a box with 50 number balls and we take out 6 of them (without putting any of them back). If $X=\textit{minimum}$ and $Y=\textit{maximum}$ then what is $f_{XY}(x,y)=P(X=x \cap Y=y)$ ?

**Attempted Sollution**: Obviously if $y-x\leq4$ then the $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$. For the non trivial part,where $y-x\geq 5$: $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{{y-x-1}\choose 4}{50\choose 6}$. This is because all the possible outcomes are $50\choose 6$ (since we don't care about the order) and the for desired outcomes we want to pick 4 out of all the balls between $x,y$ which are $y-x-1$.

Now, in my notes, the suggested answer is  $5\cdot6\cdot\frac{{y-x-1}\choose 4}{50\choose 6}$. Which answer is correct and if mine is wrong, where is the fault ?

Comment: well, since $y-x\geq 5$, $x-y-1\leq -6$ so I don't really see how any of the two answer can be right.

Comment: @P.Quinton You are right, In the binomials I meant to write $y-x-1$.

Comment: I believe the answer in the notes is correct.  While you don't care the order of selection of the $6$ balls for counting the total number of distinguishable configurations (hence your denominator is correct), you *do* care which of the six is chosen for the lower limit ($x$) and the upper limit ($y$), so the remaining four available balls for the "between" values are known.  You can't have one of the balls the lower value ($x$) and then permit it to be one of the other balls "in between."  Thus $6$ balls that could be the lower, and then only $5$ could be the upper.  You need the $6 \cdot 5$.